# What does "Fills now my cup" mean?

Tags: meaning, poetry, german-language, rainer-maria-rilke

In Rilke's poem "[Pietà](https://poets.org/poem/pieta-0)", there is this sentence:

> **Fills now my cup**, and past thought is my fulness thereof. I harden as a stone sets hard at its heart.

What does "Fills now my cup" mean?

In Italian, this is traslated as "misfortune" or "misery".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your assumption is correct; it means “misery”.

In the German original, the line reads

> Jetzt wird mein Elend voll,

which literally translates as

> Now my misery becomes full